# nsis uninstaller not deleting registry for electron app - nsh script

Tags: windows, registry, electron, nsis, electron-builder

I've set my electron app to auto-start on windows:

```
app.setLoginItemSettings({
    openAtLogin: true,
    path: process.execPaths
})
```

This adds an entry to registry at location `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\electron.app my app`

I'm using [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) to package my app.

It's mention [there](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#NsisOptions-include) that I can add a script `installer.nsh` at the time of nsis uninstallation.

Here's my custom **installer.nsh**:

```
!macro customUnInstall
    SetRegView 64
     DeleteRegKey /ifempty SHCTX "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\electron.app.my app"
    SetRegView 32
     DeleteRegKey /ifempty SHCTX "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\electron.app.my app"
 !macroend
```

And lastly, I mentioned it in package.json:

```
"nsis": {
      "runAfterFinish": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
      "include": "build/installer.nsh"
    }
```

But, still when I uninstall my app the entry is left in the registry.

How to remove this entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DeleteRegKey` deletes keys but I'm guessing your run entry is actually [a value](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090204-00/?p=19263). Use `DeleteRegValue` to delete values:

```
DeleteRegValue HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" "electron.app my app"
```

Why are you using SHCTX? Use HKCU if you know it is always written to HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Comment: SHCTX will be either HKLM (when installing for all users) or HKCU (when installing for the current user) http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Add_uninstall_information_to_Add/Remove_Programs so it seems it has auto detect which would be better if i'm not wrong

Comment: and thank you very much for the quick response, it worked. it's midnight here and wanted to fix it before going to sleep.

Comment: on a side note do you happen to know some variable which I can use instead of hardcoding "electron.app my app"?

Comment: SHCTX is not auto detected, the script has to change it. It does default to HKCU however IIRC. I don't know anything about electron builder.