# electron-builder: How can I remove deeplinking protocols once the program is uninstalled?

Tags: windows, electron, deep-linking, electron-builder

I am working on a project using electron and electron-builder. I have implemented deeplinking protocols in my package.json file. after removing the app on windows the deeplinking protocol still persists. I need this to not persist.

i have tried:
1) deleting my %appdata%\program folder as-well
2) restarting my pc after uninstallation. 
3) clearing my browser's cache.

```
{
  "name": "program",
  //...
  "scripts": {
    //...
  },
  "build": {
    //...
    "protocols": {
      "name": "electron-deep-linking",
      "schemes": [
        "deeplinkingURI"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "artifactName": "program.${ext}",
      "target": [
        {
          "arch": [
            "ia32",
            "x64"
          ],
          "target": "nsis-web"
        }
      ]
    },
    //...
  },
  //...
}
```

after uninstalling my program, the deeplinking still works (it does not launch the app because it obviously has been uninstalled, but a prompt still appears attempting to launch nothing).

I suspect that something remains within my windows registry. 
NOTE: this problem does not occur on macOS

Answer (score 0):

You have to **delete** the registry path

"**Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\your-deeplink-protocol**"

Answer (score -1):

So I've figured out the answer to my own question (not me but colleagues). there is a registry file under computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\deeplinkingurl that must be deleted at uninstall via script.

there is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210665/nsis-uninstaller-not-deleting-registry-for-electron-app-nsh-script) (that i did not see before, forgive me) that gives more details.